# Combine multiple rows into single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have below table :- table1

```
 ID        Desc

 1         ABC

 2         DEF

 3         GHI

 3         JKL

 4         MNO

 4         PQR

 4         STU
```

I want to show data as :-

```
 ID      Desc

 1         ABC

 2         DEF

 3         GHI

           JKL

 4         MNO

           PQR

           STU
```

I tried to make it as :-

```
select distinct ID , Desc from table1
```

But its not working.

Comment: this sounds like something that should be done on the presentation layer not in data access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Sql server its possible :

```
   Select distinct ID , stuff((SELECT  ','+Description FROM #a a WHERE 
   t.id=a.id for xml path('')),1,1,'') Description
   from #a T


  Output :  Id        Desc
            1         ABC
            2         DEF
            3         GHI,JKL
            4         MNO,PQR,STU
```

Answer (score 2):

for what i know you can't, you have to modify the look of your table after the request (for example in html)

Answer (score 2):

This needs to be handled in presentation layer but you can query as below:

```
Select Case when Row_Number() over(Partition by Id order by Id) = 1 then Id else Null end as Id, 
    [Desc] from #data
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query will generate the desired result.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (Rank() Over(ORDER BY id ASC)) = (Row_Number() Over (ORDER BY id ASC)) THEN id ELSE NULL END as ID, desc FROM table1
```